# Unity Netcode asks me for adding a ServerRPC suffix AFTER the method that i want to make as a ServerRPC

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

i need some help with NGO.

I wrote a method and added a [ServerRPC] attribute (didn't forget about NetworkBehaviour instead of MonoBehaviour)

```
[ServerRpc]
        public void ServerSpawnBlue(Vector3 pos)
        {
        GameObject newBluCube = Instantiate(BlueCube, pos, Quaternion.identity, playerParent);
        newBluCube.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();
        }
```

MS Visual Studio has no complaints with it...

But Unity asked me for some sick idea.

[image]

I made it just to try, but of course it didn't work.

```
public void ServerSpawnBlue(Vector3 pos)
        {
        GameObject newBluCube = Instantiate(BlueCube, pos, Quaternion.identity, playerParent);
        newBluCube.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn();
        }
        [ServerRpc]
```

[image]

What is this? A package bug? Compatibility error(impossible, because i imported it from package manager)? What should i do with this problem?

I cleaned library of project, i reipmorted the NGO package, but nothing helped.

Comment: What they mean by `method must end` is not at the end of the method's body but at the end of the method's name ;) -> `[ServerRpc] public void ServerSpawnBlueServerRpc` ... tbh a quite stupid limitation given the fact that you already have an according attribute anyway ^^

Comment: @derHugo, that's what i am talking about. I think that problem is just an compatibility error, but it doesn't mean that i don't need to fix this.

Comment: I just told you what they mean: name your method `[ServerRpc] public void ServerSpawnBlueServerRpc(Vector3 pos){ ... }` and you should be fine

Comment: @derHugo, that worked. Thank you. Jesus, what a humanitarian leaked in the Unity office? Photon Unity Network didn't ask me for that.

Comment: yeah .. as said it feels extremely redundant to require both a specific attribute + a specific name suffix ... I would kinda expect the attribute already handling that ... Afaik Unity doesn't completely make Netcode themselves - they just bought it (same as previously UNet and Mirror) and adobt things slightly